# firebase admin sdk not finding firestore data

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have configured my firebase admin service account like below (with the service key finding the correct file):

```
let admin = require("firebase-admin");

let serviceAccount = require("../serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "URL"
});
```

I am trying to do a simple retrieval of data from the firestore database. I am calling executing a simple query on the firestore database using the function below.

```
exports.listTrainers = functions.region('europe-west2').https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  try{
    const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('users').where('role', '==', 'trainer').get();
    const users = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    console.log(users);
    return(users);
  } catch (err) {
    console.info(`Error: ${err}`);
  }
});
```

However, this retrieves no data. The data exists and I can retrieve the data using the standard firebase.firestore() method (with the correct config), however the admin sdk doesn't find any data. Am I missing something?

The console log executes without errors and the data returned is simply a empty array:

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "listTrainers"
i []
i  functions: Finished "listTrainers" in ~1s
```

Comment: What data is the database is supposed to be returned (please be specific - show a screenshot so we can see for ourselves)? What does the function logs say?

Comment: The data is 3 users in the database (this data 100% exists in the db and using the standard firebase.firestore() method retrieves this data but always empty when using the admin sdk)

Comment: How did you create serviceAccountKey.json?  Are you sure the service account is pointing to the project that you expect?

Comment: I created the file in the dashboard of the correct project yes - the database url is also correct (copied straight from the firebase dashboard for the project), is there any other config required after simply generating the file from the dashboard and importing it into the project?

Comment: I suggest editing the question to show the compete set of steps anyone can take to reproduce is this problem form a fresh project.  The Admin SDK (which wraps the Google Cloud SDK) doesn't get queries wrong. Something else is going on that we can't see.

Comment: BTW the database url is only for Realtime Database. It does not apply to Cloud Firestore.

Comment: Ok great thanks for that. I will post a more detailed question when I get the time.

Comment: Is it possible (I am running this locally and using firebase emulators) that the admin sdk is actually only looking at the firestore emulated database (which would have nothing in it)?

Comment: This is on my development project so I ran ```firebase emulators:start --only functions``` and the expected data is coming back. Apologies I missed out the I haven't been using the firestore emulator on this project.